# How to output xml file as text in u-sql?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, u-sql

I've a XML file that I need to output as text, how can I do that? What is the best and efficient way to get text output via u-sql?

INPUT XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <rss version="2.0">
        <channel>
            <title>abstract.xml</title>
            <link>download.wikimedia.org/enwiki/20171103</link>
            <description>Wikimedia dump updates for enwiki</description>
            <item>
                <title>download.wikimedia.org/enwiki/20171103</title>
                <link>download.wikimedia.org/enwiki/20171103</link>
                <description>
                    <a href="download.wikimedia.org/enwiki/20171103/…" />
                </description>
                <pubDate>Sun, 05 Nov 2017 21:11:20 GMT</pubDate>
            </item>
        </channel>
    </rss>
```

This is my xml and I'm trying with below code to retrieve its data.

```
REFERENCE ASSEMBLY [Microsoft.Analytics.Samples.Formats]; 
@wiki = EXTRACT title string, 
                link string //abst string 
        FROM @input 
        USING new Microsoft.Analytics.Samples.Formats.Xml.XmlExtractor(
            "doc", 
            new SQL.MAP<string,string> { 
                    {"title","title" }, 
                    {"link","link" } 
            } 
        );
```

Comment: Did you already read [the docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt621345.aspx)?

Comment: Yeah peter I've gone through this, but I want to read the content of xml and plot that data as text file, how can I do that?

Comment: How does the xml look like and what output do you want to get from it, can you show?

Comment: <rss version="2.0">
<channel>
<title>abstract.xml</title>
<link>http://download.wikimedia.org/enwiki/20171103</link>
<description>Wikimedia dump updates for enwiki</description>
<item>
<title>http://download.wikimedia.org/enwiki/20171103</title>
<link>http://download.wikimedia.org/enwiki/20171103</link>
<description>
<a href="http://download.wikimedia.org/enwiki/20171103/enwiki-20171103-abstract.xml">enwiki-20171103-abstract.xml</a>
</description>
<pubDate>Sun, 05 Nov 2017 21:11:20 GMT</pubDate>
</item>
</channel>
</rss>

Comment: This is my xml and I'm trying with below code to retrieve its data.
REFERENCE ASSEMBLY [Microsoft.Analytics.Samples.Formats];
@wiki = 
 EXTRACT title string, 
 link  string
 //abst string
 FROM @"https://dumps.wikimedia.org/enwiki/latest/enwiki-latest-abstract.xml-rss.xml"//"clean/Test.xml" 
 USING new Microsoft.Analytics.Samples.Formats.Xml.XmlExtractor("doc",
  new SQL.MAP<string,string> { 
    {"title","title" },
    {"link","link" }
   }
 );

Comment: Can you please move your examples into the question above to make it more readable?

Answer (score 1):

There is a great example from Microsoft showed here:

https://github.com/Azure/usql/tree/master/Examples/DataFormats/Microsoft.Analytics.Samples.Formats

You can just bind the .DLL file and refer to it in your u-sql project.

I've used it a lot in the past for extracting and outputting both json and xml.